# I killed a hostile mercenary in the Bar area and now everybody is hostile there!

Tags: stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl

Strangely, a hostile Merc spawned in the Bar area. I shot him and I could hear the speakers saying that there is a murderer in the area. When I came back later, as soon as I enter the area, most NPCs become hostile against me. Also, once I enter the area, I am suddenly no longer friends with the Duty faction.

How can I redeem my status? Since this status was awarded unfairly - due to a bug I guess - is there any cheat to fix this?

I played for quite a while before noticing the issue, so loading an earlier save is not an option.

I am playing Vanilla S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Shadow of Chernobyl.

Answer (score 1):

You sure that was an enemy? If the crosshair is yellow when aiming at the NPC, it's an ally. If red, then obviously he's up to no good. I don't remember any enemies appearing there when I first played, they would only become hostile if you disobeyed them.

Also, **do not forget to save!** The series is fairly old and doesn't really seem to autosave. Often I was lucky enough to pass the hardest parts in one attempt, and then I died later on for whatever reason, realized I forgot to save, and spent another million attempts trying to pass that one hard part! Don't learn it the hard way!

As for cheats, I'd prefer not to use such. But I do know that the game has a developer console (I think by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>?).